# loop through buttons similar to image slider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Is there a way to create a function on the slider up/slide down buttons so that it will loop through the active state?

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'    
import SliderUp from '@svg/icons/slider-up.svg'    
import SliderDown from '@svg/icons/slider-down.svg'

export const Slide=()=> {    
    // this toggles the state between active and hidden components    
    const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);
    const toggleTab = (index:number) => {
      setToggleState(index);
    };
    
    return (    
    <>      
    <div>               
       <button className='transition-colors duration-500 ease-in-out hover:text-orange-500'>
                <SliderUp/> // svg
            </button>
            <ul className='flex flex-col items-center space-y-3'>
                <li>
                    <button className={toggleState===1 ? "p-5" : "p-5 "}
                        onClick={() => toggleTab(1)} >
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                <button className={toggleState===2 ? "p-5" : "p-5"}
                    onClick={() => toggleTab(2)}>
                </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                <button className={toggleState===3 ? "p-5" : "p-5"}
                    onClick={() => toggleTab(3)}>
                </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button className='transition-colors duration-500 ease-in-out hover:text-orange-500'>
                <SliderDown /> // svg
            </button>
        </div>
    <div>
            <div className="w-full overflow-hidden ">
                <div
                className={toggleState === 1 ? "p-4" : "hidden"}
                >
                <TopPart/> // component
                </div>

                <div
                className={toggleState === 2 ? "p-4" : "hidden"}
                >
                <Testtext/> // component
                </div>
                <div
                className={toggleState === 3 ? "p-4" : "hidden"}
                >
                <MythicCol/> // component
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
</>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please feel free to use code-sample or code-snippet to reformat the code, if you prefer to do so (on the question). May I please understand the significance of: `className={toggleState===1 ? "p-5" : "p-5 "`. I fail to see why a ternary `?:` is required if `className` is being assigned the same value `"p-5"`. Apologies if I've overlooked anything.

Comment: well, I added different styles to it in the main project. like "hover", "transitions" and other tailwind properties. as the CSS has nothing to do with the question I'm asking and it will fill up the code too much.

Comment: To increase/decrease the `toggleState` on Slider up/down, please try adding `onClick` method something like: `onClick={() => changeState('down')}` where the method `changeState` is something like this: `const changeState = (direction = 'up') => setToggleState(prev => {const curr = direction === 'up' ? prev + 1 : prev - 1; return curr < 1 ? 1 : curr > 3 ? 3 : curr});`. This is in JavaScript - you may need to adapt it to TypeScript.

Comment: Thank you so much. you're a lifesaver. btw there is no need to adapt js code in ts, we just have to declare its types. other than that. Big thanks...